# Need to know about "lite" mode of @Bean in spring

Tags: java, spring

Full @Configuration vs “lite” @Bean mode?
In Spring documentation they have mentioned something about @Bean annotated method without @Configuration annotated class.
Can anyone please help me to get perfect example and where can it useful(in which case)?

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-standard-annotations (Concept : 1.12.1)

Comment: Just don't use it, it will lead to more problems than it solves. It basically acts as a factory method (as the documentation states) and for each bean that needs an instance of that bean it will create a fresh one (while most will think it will also produce a singleton).

Comment: Okay So you mean to say it will act as prototyped bean but originally singletone. Correct?

Comment: Yes it'll act as prototyped bean (because bean annotation acts as a factory method), and another backlash of that is that the factory method won't be able to access another bean definition so it's tricky to be able to find a use case which benefits the lite mode compared to the full mode.

Answer (score 2):

When a @Bean method is declared within a @Component annotated class or a plain class, it is not proxied and behaves as a normal java method - so it does not return an instance from the spring container but rather creates a new instance.

This article contains an explanation with examples -
https://irena-sayv.medium.com/spring-bean-annotation-what-how-and-why-24f7abe20f83

Answer (score 1):

If a bean registers through @Component, that bean will be in full mode.

If a bean registers through @Bean annotated method,

1. If that method is defined in a @Configuration class that bean is in full mode.
2. If that method is defined in a non-configuration class, that bean is in lite mode.